# Relative path not working in Pandas python in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

### my folder structure is :

```
datasets/file.csv
source/code.ipynb
```

from within i want to access the file named file.csv.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("../datasets/file.csv")
```

This is giving me the error : `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 68, saw 2`

How to access file using relative path in pandas python?
I am using Python3.6 with Anaconda in Windows 8.1 with Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Whats the delimiter (separator) used in csv ?

Answer (score 3):

The ParseError indicates that your error is in parsing the file, not locating and opening it. To verify this, try:

```
test_file = open('../datasets/file.csv')
for line in test_file:
    print(line.strip())
```

This should print out the lines in file.csv.